# Adobe AEM6 /CQ : populating field value in the page: with sightly and design dialog

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

I am populating text field field value in the current page with a component in sightly with design dialog:

I have a helper class and a model class. In a helper class I call : getResource().adaptTo(ModelClass.class); in the activate method for a normal dialog. How do I do it for design dialog ?

Comment: Post the code of Sightly and Use Class.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sightly in component html you can directly use ${currentStyle.headline},
headline is textfield